# Yii2 Pretty Url don't work in Share Hosting (Basic Template)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

I m trying to deploy a small project build with Yii2 (Basic Template) in a Share Hosting enviroment. Everything is working fine in local. 
The Host server was like below in the root directory:

```
/
---logs
---index.html
```

After reading the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html) of Yii2. I then delete the file *index.html* and upload my project folders into the root directory. It s now looking like this:

```
/
---logs
---assets
---commands
---config
---controllers
--- ...
---views
---web
--- ...
```

After trying the website i got a blank page. I then decided to create a htaccess file in the root of host server to point the **web** folder like here

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

After this i can get the index page very well with

```
www.example.com
```

and **I get a blank page** when i try to access for example (with url prettyUrl activated)

```
www.example.com/articles/list
```

But When I deactivate the prettyUrl, it s working  like for example

```
www.example.com/web/index.php?r=articles/list
```

The .htaccess in the web folder is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# Disable Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

and the url rules are set in the web.php file like below:

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'baseUrl' => '/',
        'rules' => [                        
                ...
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

                ],
    ],
```

Comment: The very first thing I'd do is introducing some garbage in the `.htaccess` file to check wheter it is being read or not. If it is, an error 500 should pop when acccessing any page

Comment: @gmc I did it and the .htaccess file are read.

Answer (score 0):

The main majority of the shared hosts disables some of the directives from the htaccess file to prevent some security issues. And if a restricted directive is found in your htaccess file you will get an 500 error page.

It's very likely that if you remove the `Options +FollowSymLinks` directive everything will work.

Additionally you can check out the apache error log for more information.

Comment: Do you have some erros in the apache error log?

Ps.: try to remove the baseUrl from the config.